# Question about left Hopf-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

I'm reading Radford's text on Hopf Algebras right now and I'm a bit confused about the definition of a left A-Hopf algebra. The definition given in the book is:

Let $A$ be a $\Bbbk$-bialgebra. A $\underline{\text{left $A$-Hopf module}}$ is a triple ($M$, $\mu$, $\rho$) where ($M, \mu$) is a left $A$-module, ($M, \rho$) is a left $A$-comodule, and
$$ \rho(a m) = a_{(1)}m_{(-1)} \otimes a_{(2)}m_{(0)}.$$

The book uses the convention of Sumless Sweedler notation that

1. $\Delta (a) = a_{(1)} \otimes a_{(2)}$
2. $\rho (m) = m_{(-1)} \otimes m_{(0)}$

I'm just looking to gain some intuition about what the axiom for the $\rho$ map in the definition is trying to convey. It's not clear to me what the meaning of this axiom is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suppose that "left $A$-Hopf algebra" in your first sentence should be a "left $A$-Hopf module", isn't it?

Secondly, concerning your question, consider the following: if $A$ is a bialgebra over the field $\Bbbk$, then the category ${{}_A\mathfrak{M}}$ of left $A$-modules is a monoidal category in such a way that the forgetful functor $\omega\colon {{}_A\mathfrak{M}} \to \mathfrak{M}$ to the category of vector spaces is a monoidal functor. That is to say, $\Bbbk$ is a left $A$-module with action provided by
$$A \otimes \Bbbk \to \Bbbk, \qquad a \otimes \lambda \mapsto \varepsilon(a)\lambda,$$
and if $M,N$ are left $A$-modules, then $M \otimes N$ is a left $A$-module with action
$$A \otimes (M \otimes N) \to M \otimes N, \qquad a \otimes (m \otimes n) \mapsto a_{(1)}\cdot m \otimes a_{(2)} \cdot n.$$
By the compatibility between the coalgebra and the algebra structure on $A$, $(A,\Delta,\varepsilon)$ is a comonoid in the monoidal category $\left({{}_A\mathfrak{M}},\otimes,\Bbbk\right)$ of left $A$-modules.

In this framework, a left Hopf module over $A$ can be defined as a comodule over the comonoid $(A,\Delta,\varepsilon)$ in the monoidal category $\left({{}_A\mathfrak{M}},\otimes,\Bbbk\right)$ and the axiom satisfied by $\rho$ states exactly that $\rho\colon M \to A \otimes M$ is a morphism of left $A$-modules.

Equivalently, you may check that also the category ${{}^A\mathfrak{M}}$ of left $A$-comodules is a monoidal category with $\otimes$ and $\Bbbk$ and that a left Hopf module over $A$ can be also defined as a left module over the monoid $(A,m,u)$ in the monoidal category $\left({{}^A\mathfrak{M}},\otimes,\Bbbk\right)$. In this case, the condition you are looking at is a condition on the action $\mu$ rather than on $\rho$ and it is telling you that $\mu\colon A \otimes M \to M$ is a morphism of left $A$-comodules.